# href is not working with onclick in anchor tag in View

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, razor, onbeforeunload

I have searched a lot and there are similar questions. One question had the exact thing I did below in code but nothing seems to work for me.

I am trying to send email using href in `<a>` tag.
It works but then it shows `alert` asking the user if they want to stay on page or leave.

To avoid this I used a flag `mailtoLinkClicked = false`
If the user clicks the link and `onbeforeunload` event is fired then the flag will be set back to false and the user will not be asked to `Leave or Stay?`

Tried multiple other workarounds but either the email is not sent at all and or the user gets the alert popup every time. Please help me out. I am stuck at this for 4 days now.

Here is the code

`MyWindow.cshtml`

//This view opens in a new window through window.open()

```
//some code

@CommonModals.ShowEmailModal()

//some code
```

`CommonModals.cshtml`

//This view has the email link in anchor tag. This method ShowEmailModal() is invoked in MyWindow.cshtml

```
@helper ShowEmailModal()
{
   <p>Contact <a tabindex=0 href='@EmailID1' onclick='mailtoLinkClicked = true;'>EmailID1</a></p>
   <p>Contact <a tabindex=0 href='@EmailID2' onclick='mailtoLinkClicked = true;'>EmailID2</a></p>
}
```

`JS`

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type=text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        mailtoLinkClicked = true;
    
        $(window).on("beforeunload", function () {
            mailtoLinkClicked = false;
            return; //returning without asking the user if they want to leave
        }

        if (some condition) {
            return "Unsaved changes! You want to leave?";
        }
     </script>
}
```

Comment: So I could be way off here but have you tried to use a button instead of an a tag? What might be happening is that while the function that handles the email works the a tag might still be reading it as a URL and trying to navigate away from the page. A button may prevent this or maybe even using preventDefault on the a tags.

Comment: @OMGDrAcula This link is a drop-down in navbar, actually, so it cannot be a button. But i have not tried preventDefault yet. I will see if that helps but the same code works in other Views, that is strange

Comment: Give preventDefault a try for sure. If it works in some views and not others I would start checking for any errors in your console and if possible start peeling back other items in the view that could be interfering with it. Sometimes it is the silliest thing.

Comment: I have also used a custom function myFunc1() that sets flag to true and then invokes myFunc2() that sets the flag back to false and handles the ```onbeforeunload``` event this way after ```return;``` it comes back to myFunc1() and the email works but if the user resends the email then myFunc2() runs multiple times. I am thinking of using stopPrapagation() to deal with this.

Comment: That also isn't a bad idea. Usually when I have users submit something I have a popup come up that mentions that it succeed or something to that effect that way it kind of slows the user a bit.